# How to create my own onChangeComplete function for input type color on React

Tags: reactjs, input, colors, react-color

With react-color https://casesandberg.github.io/react-color/ .
I can use ready-made onChangeComplete function from react-color.

But I wonder how can I create that onChangeComplete by using input type color tag.
I tried onBlur but the color won't change until user clicks or presses tab

On the other hand, using onChange keep firing updates.
Because currently I'm using redux state, so dispatching update continuously when I drag and choose color isn't a good way.

Any ideas how to create onChangeComplete?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the [code](https://github.com/casesandberg/react-color/blob/7ee60d845e5d5e11e4f6ecb895b2d9755c59d09d/src/components/common/ColorWrap.js#L30) that how react-color implemented onChangeComplete.
It is hard coded using debounce.

Comment: Hello, I am facing the same issue, can you give some example code on how to solve this? Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

It depends on how you'd like to define a change. To prevent continuous updates every time the mouse moves, you'll probably want to update Redux state only when the mouse stops moving. (This seems to be the behaviour on the [page you linked to](https://casesandberg.github.io/react-color/)).

You could use the following JavaScript to detect when the mouse stops moving:

```
let timer;

window.addEventListener('mousemove', function (e) {
  console.log('Mouse moving');
  clearTimeout(timer);
  timer = setTimeout(() => console.log('Mouse stopped'), 300);
});
```

Then, try putting the above code inside your `ComponentDidMount()` method and replace `console.log('Mouse stopped')` with whatever Redux action you want to dispatch!

`300` is the number of milliseconds without movement that will trigger the action, which could be changed depending on how sensitive you want your app to feel.

Lastly, remember to [remove the event listener](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/removeEventListener) in your `ComponentWillUnmount()` method.

Comment: Thank for your solution. I will try it. Anyways, I have found another solution which react-color is actually using and it is using debounce. I have posted the answer below for anyone interested in that.

Comment: About your solution, How can we add mousemove event into the popup native color picker ?

Comment: If you're using React class components, you can incorporate the code above into the `ComponentDidMount()` method, then trigger a function to read the colour values at that point and update state.